# OSGi profiles like Spring profiles

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle, karaf, blueprint-osgi

I have an OSGi service with two implementations. One for prod and one for testing.

Is there any way how to switch them in different envs via code? Something like [Spring profiles](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-profiles-example/)

Comment: How do you register your OSGi service now? Programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct match to profiles. What you can do is to publish both services with different service properties. On the service consumer you can then use a filter to decide which service to use.

In declarative services this filter can be changed at runtime by providing a configuration for your component. In the code you set the filter to your default like "prod" below.

```
@Reference(target="(profile=prod)")
MyService myService;
```

In the config for the component where you inject the service you can add a property to change this filter:

```
myService.target=(profile=dev)
```

Another even more common approach is to simply deploy different services for dev and prod. In your test you deploy a dummy service while in prod you deploy the real service. This approach has the advantage that it works with any DI framework in OSGi.